# Unable to access custom type array properties in lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have an attribute in a lightning component that is a custom type array

`<aura:attribute name="objClassController" type="MyController.MyParser[]" />`

I've debugged to verify that I'm getting results returned from the callback. I can see that the callback function is successful and the response contains the object array.

I'm using `aura:iteration` in the component:

```
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.objClassController.results}" var="obj">
        <tr>
            <td>{!obj.rewardId}</td>
        </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
```

Here is the main class:

```
public class MyController {

@AuraEnabled public List<MyParser> results {get; set;}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<MyParser> getRewardsInfo(string caseId) {
    List<MyParser> retval = new  List<MyParser>();
    String uid = [select Order__r.Order_Number__c from Case where Id =: caseId].Order__r.Order_Number__c;
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setEndpoint('callout:Rewards/user/'+uid+'/rewards/all');
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    retval = MyController.parse(res.getBody()); 
    return retval;
}

public static List<MyParser> parse(String json) {
    return (List<MyParser>) System.JSON.deserialize(json, List<MyParser>.class);
}
}
```

Here is the parser class:

```
public class MyParser {

    @AuraEnabled public String rewardId;
    @AuraEnabled public String rewardProgramCode;
    @AuraEnabled public String currentPoint;
    @AuraEnabled public Coupon coupon;
    @AuraEnabled public String lastActivityDate;


    public class Coupon {
        public String couponCode;
        public String status;
    }
}
```

I am not able to access the data that is returned in the `List<MyParser> results` property when using `aura:iteration`. Are the properties that are within the `MyParser` class not accessible? I've annotated the properties with `@auraEnabled` and they are public. Nothing displays when I view the component in a lightning record page, but I know the data is returned because the debug and console log statements shows data getting correctly returned. Is the dot notation I'm using to access the data incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access controller variables this way, as you would in Visualforce. Instead, you need to call the method and set the attribute appropriately.

```
<aura:attribute name="results" type="MyController.MyParser[]" />
```

---

```
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.results}" var="obj">
```

---

```
let action = component.get("c.getRewardsInfo");
action.setParams({caseId: component.get("v.recordId") });
action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
  if(result.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
    component.set("v.results", result.getReturnValue());
  } // handle ERROR, too.
}); 
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

P.S. The inner class attributes also need to be annotated:

```
public class Coupon {
    @AuraEnabled public String couponCode;
    @AuraEnabled public String status;
}
```

You can remove:

```
@AuraEnabled public List<MyParser> results {get; set;}
```

As there is no way to access the variable.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox

Comment: @Dman100 Yeah, no problem. Happy to assist!